# Как пройтись по элементам из цикла? JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Например:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('.info').each(function (e, el) {
        el(td).each?????????
    })
});
```

Не пойму как можно вызвать внутренний цикл.

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. Покажите что у вас в блоке .info. 
Больше кода. )

Comment: @ShevtsovEugene $('.info') - это <tr> только не все, а у которых есть класс .info. Так вот,  сначала мне нужно выбрать каждый <tr>, а затем пройтись по каждому его элементу, то-есть <td>

Comment: `$(this).find("td").each(...)`, а сразу то не устроит вас `$(".info td").each(...)` ?

Answer (score 0):

для поиска потомков используйте методв `find`, или в вашем случае более эффективным будет `children()`/

```
$(function(){
    $(".info").each(function(){
        $(this).children("td").each(function(){
            //$(this)  --- указывает на td
        });
    });
});
```

если в целом вам не требуется информация о родительской строек,а просто нужны действия с ячейками, то можете использовать селектор `.info td`. Хотя и тут может обратится к родительской строек через `parent`

```
$(".info td").each(function(){
     // $(this).parent() -- указывает на строку
});
```